# metamask insufficient funds for gas how do i fix this?

Tags: metamask, binance

metamask insufficient funds for gas, i'm currently using the bsc and I have 18usdt there that I want to send to binance

Answer (score 2):

You have to have the native asset (BNB) to pay for gas. You can't pay for gas costs with tokens (usdt). So you can't get the USDT out before you get some BNB in the account, somehow. So, you also can't trade the USDT to get BNB, since you can't send the USDT for trading.

Comment: can i send some bnb from binance to metamask for the gas fees in order to transfer the usdt to bnb?

Comment: Yes. Except that you're not sending the to metamask, but to the wallet manages by metamask